# Split sentence based on multiple patterns keeping delimiter

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have some sentences where the delimiting patterns are "(has|is|thinks)"

I would like to include the delimiter in the second sentence and remove all trailing spaces like so:

```
mystr1 <- "the bird is now a dog"
mystr2 <- "the small cow thinks like a dog"
mystr3 <- "the fish has become a dog"
```

results in:

```
"the bird"          "is now a dog"
"the small cow"     "thinks like a dog"
"the fish"          "has become a dog"
```

Note:
`str_split(mystr3, "(has|is|thinks)", n = 2)`

results in
`"the f"              "h has become a dog"`

since "is" is a delimiter and is part of "fish"

How best to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use positive lookahead pattern to keep the delimiters and word boundaries to avoid splitting in the middle of a word.

```
split_sent <- function(x) {
    trimws(stringr::str_split(x, '(?=\\b(has|is|thinks)\\b)', n = 2)[[1]])
}

split_sent(mystr1)
#[1] "the bird"     "is now a dog"
split_sent(mystr2)
#[1] "the small cow"     "thinks like a dog"
split_sent(mystr3)
#[1] "the fish"         "has become a dog"
```